# AG Grid Header overlaps the popup

Tags: css, angular, ag-grid-angular

I am using AG Grid for Angular to show data in tabular format. I have a column which show context menu from a cell. However context menu popup go beneath the header.

[image]

I tried setting z-index for both context menu and row via css, but looks like it doesn't take any effect.

Can anyone guide me how can I bring context menu popup over Row Header?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The parent of the popup needs to have a higher z-index than the parent of the header.